# Vaadin 7.1: parent of subwindow

Tags: vaadin7

I am using Vaadin 7.1

I have 2 layuots:

---

### |    header    |

### |     main     |

and popup window.

When I maximize the window I want it to be opened in "main" but not in whole screen.
is it possible?

When I try to do this directly I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A Window can only be added to a UI
>   using UI.addWindow(Window window)

Regards,
Oleksandr.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some javascript and custom logic for this.
First of all, you have to set the main layout id:

```
mainLayout.setId("xyz");
```

And here is the extended window:

```
public class MyWindow extends Window {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int top;
    private int left;
    private int bottom;
    private int right;

    public MyWindow() {
        setResizable(false);
        setData(WindowMode.NORMAL);
        String sourceURL = "javascript:com.xyz.foo.myfunc(" +
                "document.getElementById('xyz').getBoundingClientRect().top," +
                "document.getElementById('xyz').getBoundingClientRect().left," +
                "document.getElementById('xyz').getBoundingClientRect().bottom," +
                "document.getElementById('xyz').getBoundingClientRect().right)";
        final Link link = new Link("maximization", new ExternalResource(sourceURL));
        // set link icon if needed
        JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("com.xyz.foo.myfunc", new JavaScriptFunction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void call(JSONArray arg) throws JSONException {
                if (MyWindow.this.getData() == WindowMode.NORMAL) {
                    saveCurrentPos();
                    setPos(arg.getInt(0), arg.getInt(1), arg.getInt(2), arg.getInt(3));
                    link.setCaption("normalization"); // or set icon
                    MyWindow.this.setData(WindowMode.MAXIMIZED);
                } else {
                    setPos(top, left, bottom, right);
                    link.setCaption("maximization"); // or set icon
                    MyWindow.this.setData(WindowMode.NORMAL);
                }
            }
        });
        VerticalLayout vLayout = new VerticalLayout(link);
        vLayout.setComponentAlignment(link, Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);
        setContent(vLayout);

        // demo settings
        setWidth("200px");
        setHeight("150px");
        center();
    }

    private void saveCurrentPos() {
        left = getPositionX();
        top = getPositionY();
        right = left + (int) getWidth();
        bottom = top + (int) getHeight();
    }

    private void setPos(int top, int left, int bottom, int right) {
        setPositionX(left);
        setPositionY(top);
        setWidth(right - left, Unit.PIXELS);
        setHeight(bottom - top, Unit.PIXELS);
    }

}
```

I suggest that you write your own header with caption and closing button.